# Зачем(,) у нас не спрашивают!

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

*- Сделай то-то и то-то.

- Зачем?

**- Зачем у нас не спрашивают.***

Вроде бы для запятой нет оснований, "зачем" - член предложения. Но без неё вообще другой смысл. 
Впрочем, с запятой тоже не слишком доходчиво получается на письме.

Я выкрутился, написав **"Зачем?" у нас не спрашивают.** Но это, понятно, авторская хитрость, а как по правилам?

**UPD**
Пояснение в связи с появившимися ответам.

~1. Тире возможно (и при известных условиях необходимо) тогда, когда это ССП. По сути оно заменяет собой запятую. Но у нас нет ССП, поскольку "зачем" - член предложения.
*Когда(?) я не знаю - я не знаю когда* (но: *я не знаю, когда это будет*).
*Зачем(?) здесь не спрашивают - Здесь не спрашивают зачем* (но: *я не знаю, когда это будет*).

Зачем и когда здесь согласно общему подходу не являются отдельным предложением, но лишь членом предложения.

Обсуждаемый вариант (первый в парах) не более чем инверсия естественного порядка слов (представленного вторым членом пары). Во всяком случае я не встречал ьрактовок, что родчиненная часть ССП может состоять из одного союбзного слова. Вот в скобках - да, ССП. Но там и не одно слово.

~2. Вариант с кавычками я видел (хотя не понимаю, как можно в этом случаю опустить знак вопроса), но это именно что авторская пунктуация, не более чем паллиатив, правилами не подкрепленный. Она к тому же зрительно немного смещает акцент, заставляя считать закавыченное прямой речью.

Comment: @ behemothus, вы пишете: "Тире возможно (и при известных условиях необходимо) тогда, когда это ССП". А почему ССП, а не СПП?

Comment: По поводу того, что придаточная часть может состоять из союзного слова, см. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация.  Д. Э. Розенталь. [§ 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

Comment: @Серж *А почему ССП, а не СПП?*  Не совсем понял вопрос. Хотя здесь разницы по большому счету - никакой. Ни тем ни другим не является. И не делайте пробела после@

Comment: @Серж *см. Справочник по русскому языку* - вы имеете в виду пункт 3) ? Так там же нет запятой перед тем, что Р. назвает "придаточной частью". В справочнике РАН это есть:: ***(одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения)*** http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg115.php    Возможно, я несколько опрометчиво выразился, но я имел в виду именно современную трактовку, подразумевающую, что одно союзное слово - не предложение.

Comment: У Р. другое интересно, Он допускает запятую перед такой "придаточной частью" по условиям какого-то контекста. Вот тогда - да... Это зацепка и основание для тире при "инверсии". Но это я сейчас боюсь наверняка утверждать, подумать надо.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, здесь подходит п. 8 из §118.

> [§118. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm)
>   Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении, распадающемся на две части, ставится:
>   (...)
>   8) если вторая часть представляет собой присоединительное предложение и перед ним можно вставить слово это, которое может быть в самом предложении, например: На стене ни одного образа – дурной знак (Лермонтов); Инга была возбуждена, Левшин наблюдал за ней слишком пристально – это бросилось Клебе в глаза (Федин); Идет большая вода – это всего интереснее (Горбатов).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm

**Зачем — у нас не спрашивают.**

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Кто пойдет, как и зачем, ― об этом ни слова! [Владимир Богомолов. Иван (1957)]
>
> Вскоре он уехал из Москвы. Куда и зачем ― об этом ниже. Удивительно, как мало переменился он за эти годы. [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944)]

Comment: С точки зрения наглядности - тоже вариант, конечно. Но, строго говоря, предложение-то не БСП. "Зачем" - член предложения. Я потому и не рассматривал тире вовсе, хотя изначально рука тянулась его поставить.

Comment: Все же я думаю, здесь *зачем* выступает в качестве единственного слова придаточного предложения.  В отличие от цельных по смыслу сочетаний, таких как "знаю зачем".

Comment: *выступает в качестве единственного слова придаточного предложения*. Я и рад бы принять такое как тезис. Но  вы хоть раз сталкивались с трактовкой, что придаточная часть ССП может состоять из одного союзного слова? Остальное - см. UPD в тексте вопроса.

Comment: А да еще про ваши примеры. Помимо того, что там придаточное(?) явно не из одного слова состоит, они не позволяют произвести инверсию своих частей. Поэтому сведение к ССП тут весьма условно, а тире можно обїяснить и по-другому. Перечислением при обобщающем слове "это". Без этого слова все вполне естественно смотрится и без знаков - по крайней мере во втором примере. **"Куда и зачем, скажу ниже"** - ну чем плохо?!

Answer (score 1):

**"Зачем" у нас не спрашивают.**

Это как бы **прямая речь, повторение вопроса**. Сравнить: Зачем это надо? – "Зачем это надо" у нас не спрашивают.

**Знак вопроса** можно поставить, но можно и не ставить. Вопросительная интонация необязательна.

**Пояснение:**

**Нет в приведенном предложении паузы**, обычной для изъяснительных СПП.

Сравнить: *Зачем – было непонятно никому*. У Розенталя: *Он придёт, но когда — не знаю.* http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Чтобы применить правило, **надо определить вид синтаксической конструкции.** Очевидно, что это СПП (не БСП и не ССП), так как изъяснительная часть состоит из одного союзного слова ***зачем.***

2) **В СПП в общем случае возможны варианты постановки знаков: запятая, тире или их отсутствие.** Третий вариант относится к нашему случаю, и **Розенталь разрешает не ставить знак или поставить запятую при интонационном выделении.** Тот же Розенталь **разрешает заменять запятую тире,** если изъяснительная часть находится в препозиции и особенно в том случае, когда структура главного и придаточного предложений различна. Из всего этого, по Розенталю, получаем ответ: **Зачем – у нас не спрашивают.**

3) Но это еще не всё. **Обратимся к смыслу предложения: что мы, собственно, хотим сказать.** Вариантов два: (1) у нас причины не объясняют; (2) слово "зачем" здесь говорить не принято. Первый вариант уже разобран, а вот второй нет.

Итак, у нас слово "зачем" не говорят. Или проще: **"зачем?" у нас не спрашивают.**

**И это тоже по Розенталю, только предложение в этом случае простое, а дословное высказывание оформлено как дополнение.**

4) Я так понимаю поставленную задачу, хотя вовсе не рассчитываю, что кто-нибудь меня поддержит. Но мне хотелось вам, то есть всему обществу, это рассказать.

Comment: Ой, Jasmin, ну это же все рассуждения без отсылок к правилам. Тире не подходит (вроде бы) потому, что это не ССП. В тексте вопроса сейчас дам пояснения.